# Multiplying fixed-point types in Solidity

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, fixed-point

I would like to define a function like this:

```
function convert(ufixed x) external pure returns (uint256 result) {
    result = x * 1e18;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not compile:

> TypeError: type ufixed128x18 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.

I went ahead and casted `x` to `uint256`:

```
result = uint256(x) * 1e18;
```

But this didn't work either:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Fixed point types not implemented.

I have read the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html?highlight=fixed#fixed-point-numbers), and I understand that fixed-point types cannot be assigned to or from. However, all I want is to multiply them by a pre-factor.

Is this still not possible to do in Solidity just yet?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment we cannot do practically anything with the `ufixed` type.

You could implement your own `UFixed` type or use a library that handles "fix point" number arithmetics.

Take a look at the following `UFixed` custom type and `FixedMath` library to abstract the details of the arithmetics operations for this type:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

type UserId is uint256;
type UFixed is uint256;

/// A minimal library to do fixed point operations on UFixed.
library FixedMath {
    uint constant multiplier = 10**18;

    /// Adds two UFixed numbers. Reverts on overflow, 
    /// relying on checked arithmetic on uint256.
    function add(UFixed a, UFixed b) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(UFixed.unwrap(a) + UFixed.unwrap(b));
    }
    /// Multiplies UFixed and uint256. Reverts on overflow,
    /// relying on checked arithmetic on uint256.
    function mul(UFixed a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(UFixed.unwrap(a) * b);
    }
    /// Take the floor of a UFixed number.
    /// @return the largest integer that does not exceed `a`.
    function floor(UFixed a) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return UFixed.unwrap(a) / multiplier;
    }
    /// Turns a uint256 into a UFixed of the same value.
    /// Reverts if the integer is too large.
    function toUFixed(uint256 a) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(a * multiplier);
    }
}

contract Contract {
    using FixedMath for UFixed;

    mapping(UserId => User) public users;

    struct User {
        UserId id;
        string name;
    }

    function getUser(UserId userId) public view returns(User memory) {
        return users[userId];
    }

    function add(UFixed a, UFixed b) public pure returns(UFixed) {
        return a.add(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ironically, I've actually built [my own fixed-point math library](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math). I needed this convertor function as an internal utility for the library tests.

Comment: Oh wow! That's awesome! I've seen this library being mentioned in multiple places. Good job!